# RabbitMQ get last message

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have Server which sends count of sellers to unauthorized clients via RabbitMQ.
How can new client get last message from RabbitMQ?

For example:

- 9:00 - 1 seller online (Server sends "1")
- 9:03 - 2 sellers online (Server sends "2")
- 9:04 - 1st client connented
- 9:04 - 2nd client connented
- 9:05 - 3 sellers online (Server sends "3")
- 9:06 - 3rd client connected

So, if I use *direct* or *fanout* exchange type, 2nd client doesn't receive "2 sellers online". How can new client get last message?

Comment: I'm afraid RabbitMQ doesn't support `stack` (i.e. LIFO structure) instead of `queue` (i.e. FIFO). But if you need only THE last message you can restrict the size of the queue to 1, so you'd have only the last one at a time

Comment: But still probably what you want doesn't fit in message queues world. Think again what you want and how it fits to RabbitMQ.

Comment: would you use this to monitor iot devices status(es) ? @pkuderov

Comment: @Imnotapotato well, honestly, too much time has passed — I am not proficient to answer even the topic question ATM :) As far as I remember and understand queues like RabbitMQ, I would not — I think centralized registry that accepts statues updates directly from iots (push-based) or periodically pings them (pull-based) is probably a simpler and better choice. But take my words with a grain of salt.

Comment: @pkuderov sorry bit I am not sure I understand. You would not use RMQ for handling an IoT device state? what do you mean by push/pull-based?

Comment: @Imnotapotato I mean, from what you've described there's no immediate need for the use of queues (like RMQ) — a simple centralized handler could be enough for that. If a changed state event requires a lot of processing, and you have many IoTs then maybe. Push/pull means who initiate a state check: IoT itself sends heartbeats or they are initiated externally from the checker.
I probably just haven't understood the exact architecture you have in mind.